# Angular 4 | How to use event emitter in for loop

Tags: angular

How can i detect the changes of my for loop using event emitter?

```
getdata(){
for(let mydata of this.data) {
            if (mydata.Zone == 1) {
                this.zoneOne.push(mydata);
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 2) {
                this.zoneTwo.push(mydata);
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 3) {
                this.zoneThree.push(mydata);
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 4) {
                this.zoneFour.push(mydata);
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 5) {
                this.zoneFive.push(mydata);
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 6) {
                this.zoneSix.push(mydata);
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 7) {
                this.zoneSeven.push(mydata);
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 8) {
                this.zoneEight.push(mydata);
            }
        }
    }

this.timer= setInterval(() => { 
        this.getdata();
    }, (this.counter*1000));
```

I want to display only once when the interval is done. but it seems it always pushing my data and i get multiple value on my screen. how can i handle this to change only the array if theres new data on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use setInterval, it will keep firing the function after said intervals. You need to use setTimeout instead. Something like this:

```
setTimeout(() => { 
    this.getdata();
}, (this.counter*1000));
```

setTimeout will fire the function only once and not repeatedly.